# tensorflow 2 from Sequential to Functional

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have the following autoencoder model defined using the Sequential API:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, Dense, Lambda, Reshape, Activation, Dropout
    def test_seq(X_train, epochs):
        model = keras.Sequential()
        #encoder
        model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(6,2),\
                          activation='relu',\
                          padding='same',
                          dilation_rate=1,\
                          strides=1,\
                          input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1)))
        model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    
        # Latent space
        model.add(Dense(2))
    
        #decoder
        model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(6,2),\
                          activation='relu',\
                          padding='same',
                          dilation_rate=1,\
                          strides=1))
        model.add(Dropout(0.1))
        
        model.add(Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(6,2),\
                          activation='relu',\
                          padding='same'))
    
                  
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae', 'mape'])
        print(model.summary())
        print()
        
        print('TRAINING...')
        history = model.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=0)
        print('DONE !!')
    
        return model, history
```

[image]

I want to rewrite it using the Functional API to be able to return the encoder and decoder separately. My attempt is:

```py
def test_fun(X_train, epochs, latent_dim):
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, Dense, Lambda, Reshape
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout, BatchNormalization
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
    from tensorflow.keras.losses import mean_squared_error
    import keras.backend as K 
 
    
    ### Encoder
    e_i     = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1), name='enc_input') # input layer
    cx      = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(6,2),\
                         activation='relu',\
                         padding='same',
                         dilation_rate=1,\
                         strides=1,\
                         input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],1), name='enc_c1')(e_i)
    cx      = Dropout(0.1)(cx)

    
    ### Latent space
    x       = Dense(latent_dim, name='latent_space')(cx)
    
    
    ### Instantiate encoder
    encoder = Model(e_i, x, name='encoder')
    print(encoder.summary())


    ### Decoder
    d_i   = Input(shape=(latent_dim, 1), name='decoder_input')
    cx    = Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(6,2),\
                       activation='relu',\
                       padding='same',
                       dilation_rate=1,\
                       strides=1, name='dec_c1')(d_i)
    cx    = Dropout(0.1)(cx) 
    
    o     = Conv2D(1, kernel_size=(6,2),\
                      activation='relu',\
                      padding='same',\
                      name='decoder_output')(cx)

    # Decoder instantiation
    decoder = Model(d_i, o, name='decoder')
    print(decoder.summary())


    # Instantiate AE
    ae_outputs = decoder(encoder(e_i))
    ae         = Model(e_i, ae_outputs, name='ae')


    # Compile AE
    ae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae', 'mape'],\
                experimental_run_tf_function=False)

    # Train autoencoder
    history = ae.fit(X_train, X_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=0)

    return encoder, decoder, ae, history
```

However, this returns an input size error for the decoder:
[image]

Why does it expect ndim=4?

On a second thought, how can the Seauential model work without padding='valid' in the first layer of the decoder. Btw, I receive the same error even with padding='valid'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not with the padding. According to keras documentation :

> Conv2D layer takes an input of 4-dim i.e (batch_size, rows, cols, channels)

But the input you have given to layer "dec_c1" is of shape (latent_dim, 1) so I would suggest you to change the shape of Input layer "decoder_input" to a 3-dim format something like this

`d_i   = Input(shape=(latent_dim, 1, 1), name='decoder_input')`

Comment: Thanks, with `Input(shape=(180, latent_dim, latent_dim), name='decoder_input')` the model seems to have the right dimensions (the summaries of the two models are the same).
However, the results are very different from one model to the other. The quality of the one defined with the Functional API are much worse. 
Have you ever encountered something similar? Where could the error be?

Comment: I think it can happen for various reasons on such instance is using a kernel initialiser